# How do I assign a value from response to body for another post data?

Tags: reactjs

so I have 2 post data functions, the first is to upload photo/file, another one is for add a document.
in the API for add document, there are 3 body that need to be filled. name(string), location(string), and photo(string).
I already created the function for upload photo, and I get the return link of the url path for photo.

My question is, how do I assign the link from url path to body add document for photo(string)?

json for add document :
[image: AddDocument]

json for uploaded photo:
[image]

code for upload photo:

```js
try {
      const postFileReq = await axios.post(
        "https://spda-api.onrender.com/api/file/upload",
        formData,
        options
      );
      const postFileRes = await postFileReq.data.image;
      if (postFileReq.status === 200) {
        setPhotoUrl(postFileRes);
        console.log("postFileRes", postFileRes);
        // console.log("photoUrl", photoUrl);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const err = error as AxiosError;
      console.log(err.response?.data);
    }
```

code for add document:

```js
try {
      const postDocReq = await axios.post(
        "https://spda-api.onrender.com/api/admin/documents",
        {
          name: field.name,
          location: field.location,
          photo: photoUrl,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      const postDocRes = await postDocReq.data;
      if (postDocReq.status === 200) {
        setShowSnackbar(true);
        router.reload();
        console.log(postDocRes);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const err = error as AxiosError;
      console.log(err.response?.data);
    }
```

i already tried using useState to assign but it still not working, anyone have an idea?

```
 const [photoUrl, setPhotoUrl] = useState("");
```

My complete code: https://pastebin.com/Rb5xX08z

Comment: You mean the response you are getting from post from first API data , you need to pass that to the second API right?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Alright so what you need you to do is call the second api in the success method of the first call. I will jump to the code directly with `async/await`. You can do it with `then` as well.

You can handle it inside your if condition 200 success. So like once it is successfull call the second function then. But I have shown with async/await like mentioned

```
import axios from 'axios'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [secondData, setSecondData] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://first-api.com');
      setData(response.data);
      //if first api was successful,call the second api
      const secondResponse = await axios.get(`https://second-api.com/${response.data.id}`);
      setSecondData(secondResponse.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Data from first API: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
      <p>Data from second API: {JSON.stringify(secondData)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```